# OnConfiguring for DbContext - code not being run - ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dnx

I have this code:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(local);Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the description, this will be fired on new instance of TestDbContext. I have code that creates a new context:

```
TestDbContext ctx = new TestDbContext();
```

I was expecting OnConfiguring will be fired so I can set my connection string but code does not pass through here (I have breakpoint). Do I need anything else to setup.

Comment: What is the version of EF you are using?

Comment: @Vasanth: using EF 7

Answer (score 0):

My DI leading to the `OnConfiguring(..)` not firing also.

For me, I was able to add a ctor to resolve the issue

```
protected MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

}
```

or if you'd prefer..

```
 protected MyDbContext() : base(new DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>())
 {

 }
```